# Why has D.Hutchinson been banned for 28 years?

Tags: discussion

@scaaahu noticed in the Ivory Tower chat that https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/91603/d-hutchinson?tab=profile has been banned for 28 years. Incredible! I took a look at D.Hutchinson's posts at academia.SE and found nothing bad. Really nothing. I might be missing something, but which kind of offense would lead to such a long ban? In practical terms, this is "forever". The way we know the stackexchange site today, it need not even exist for such a long time span. Some of us might even be happily pushing up the daisies by then.

What I could imagine is that the user might be way too young to discuss academic issues, say, 5 years old. Then, about 20 years might make sense.

Comment: We will probably never know the details of what happened because moderators cannot reveal them, but since the ban is network wide, the offense might be related to his activity elsewhere and not specifically to that here on Academia. Afaik, common issues that can bring to long suspensions are sockpuppeting, repeated rude behaviour and such.

Comment: Voting on Meta is different. Questions about the suspension of a specific user are usually not answerable. and the downvotes probably just reflect this. I don't think anyone has taken your question personally.

Comment: Every community has its own personality, and reactions to the same type of inquiry can be quite different. Maybe it also depends on the degree of affection between the community and the suspended user.

Comment: I will just mention that this question on Meta Stack Exchange is (to some extent) related to this specific suspension: [Could network-wide suspensions last longer than 10 years?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310376)

Comment: The first chat message regarding this topic is [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44897082#44897082), in case you are interested with it.

Comment: Stack Exchange's policy on this kind of issues is "no, we won't tell you the details. Trust the moderators or find yourself another website". Just so you know.

Comment: Apparently another user just got banned and I can not really understand why. I think he had annoying & paranoid behaviour.

Answer (score 8):

The suspension is network wide. This means the suspension was issued by a stack exchange community moderator employee. As for what the offense was, it is unlikely to be made public. Suspensions that long are rare and in my experience do not have common underlying behaviors beyond being unwelcome. It is unlikely to be useful to look at the user's activity since there is likely deleted content spread across multiple sites. Avoiding a suspension like this is not something you likely need to worry about as users receive numerous warning prior to such a suspension.

Answer (score 8):

> I took a look at D.Hutchinson's posts at academia.SE and found nothing bad. Really nothing.

The vast majority of suspensions is issued for either vote abuse or posting delete-worthy content (usually lots of it), such as offensive posts, spam, etc. Either way, regular users won’t see what is problematic, because it was either never visible to them or, well, deleted. Even [the privilege of seeing deleted posts](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) won’t allow you to track down deleted posts, since it doesn’t allow you to search for deleted posts by a given user. Looking at it the other way round, if you could still find suspension-worthy content by the user, this would be worrisome or it was missed during cleaning up (either way, flag it).

Admittedly, there are some suspended users whose undeleted content exhibits borderline behaviour or otherwise gives you a strong hint at why they were suspended, but these are only about half of the suspended users.

And even this is only half the reason why you cannot find anything; the other half being that this is a network suspension.